# Is the structure of my Prolog expression isomorphic to the structure of the Liar Paradox?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Is the structure of my Prolog expression isomorphic to the structure of the Liar Paradox?

We assume that Prolog does not evaluate the meanings of the term "not" and "true" and only evaluates the the structure of the expression.

**Liar Paradox in English:** "This sentence is not true."

```
?- LP = not(true(LP)).
LP = not(true(LP)).

?- unify_with_occurs_check(LP, not(true(LP))).
false.
```

---

After careful review by others it seems correct to say that the above expression is isomorphic to the Liar Paradox even when we ignore the English meanings of the terms "not" and "true" and replace them with "foo" and "bar". **It is the pathological self-reference of the Liar Paradox that Prolog rejects.**

```
?- LP = foo(bar(LP)).
LP = foo(bar(LP)).

?- unify_with_occurs_check(LP, foo(bar(LP))).
false.
```

**The Clock & Mellish text in my answer explains the details of why
unify_with_occurs_check rejects LP.** ---

Comment: @brebs The point of this is that some otherwise undecidable decision problems can be recognized and rejected as unsound rather than the current [received view] that the undecidability of these decision problems derives a fundamental limit to computation.

Comment: It's not right, though. It's not recognizing "this sentence" as a self-reference. It's just doing its simple job of recognizing that the 2 terms are different yet one refers to the other.

Comment: @brebs **<Clocksin & Mellish>** Finally, a note about how Prolog matching sometimes differs from the unification used in Resolution. Most Prolog systems will allow you to satisfy goals like: equal(X, X). ?- equal(foo(Y), Y). that is, they will allow you to match a term against an uninstantiated subterm of itself. In this example, foo(Y) is matched against Y, which appears within it. As a result, Y will stand for foo(Y), which is foo(foo(Y)) (because of what Y stands for), which is foo(foo(foo(Y))), and soon. So Y ends up standing for some kind of infinite structure. 
**</Clocksin & Mellish>**

Comment: I know. But, you're not giving Prolog "This sentence is not true.", for Prolog to identify that there is a self-reference through some meaningful logic. You are merely providing 2 terms for which `unify_with_occurs_check` is going to fail. You need to have an example for which you would do this task and expect `unify_with_occurs_check` to **succeed**, where you *haven't* practically given Prolog the answer yourself.

Comment: @brebs My purpose has always been to show that the pathological self-reference (PSR) that makes certain kinds of decision problems undecidable is a semantic error in the problem specification and thus not any limitation of computability. When the PSR structure of the Liar Paradox is encoded in Prolog it is rejected by Prolog as unsound.

Comment: Show a similar Prolog query which **succeeds**. Having a query always fail is of no use. Your "encoding" is merely a pretense.

Comment: @brebs I have spent years on this. Prior to finding that Prolog rejects such expressions I created Minimal Type Theory that does this same thing. https://liarparadox.org/MTT_Diagram.png The cycle that MTT detects is the same cycle that unify_with_occurs_check detects.

Comment: But you're giving Prolog the cycle. You're doing 99% of the work for Prolog. Why would you think that is useful?

Comment: @brebs It proves that decision problem instances (such as the halting problem counter-examples) having the pathological self-reference that I encoded in Prolog are merely unsound and thus place no actual limit on computation.

Comment: It does not prove that, because you haven't shown a **success**, as I keep stating. Show us how something that's not self-referencing has a different result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254499/discussion-between-polcott-and-brebs).

Comment: Don't edit answers into your question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[image]

Prolog correctly rejects any expression having the same pathological self referential structure as the Liar Paradox with its unify_with_occurs_check/2.

[image]

Comment: Me pointing out that the logic is daft, is being used as the answer - how ludicrous.

Comment: @brebs Your answer on the Prolog group does not say that the logic is daft. It correctly says that Prolog correctly rejects any expression having the same self-referential form as the Liar Paradox.

Comment: Without a predicate which succeeds, for comparison, it's meaningless. As I have repeatedly stated, and you have always dodged answering.

Comment: @brebs I quoted Clocksin and Mellish that explains all of the details. If you can't understand it on this basis then you can't understand it. If you knew what a directed graph is then you would know that a cycle in the directed graph of the evaluation of an expression prevents this expression from being evaluated. **The key aspect of the Liar Paradox is that it has a cycle in its evaluation graph.**